# Machine Learning and perceptrons

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm new in python so take it easy with me.

So I got a project to complete about perceptrons.

They gave me a dataset containing about 1300 lines.From this dataset the perceptron will train it self to increase accuracy and return me a number.

I need to input 804082 for example and the program return me a number and the accuracy percentage.

I got no idea where to start been searching for tutorials and guides all over the web with no results.

My question is can someone guide me or link me a tutorial? Every help is accepted.

Thanks in advance!

This is from the dataset:

```
    INPUTS, RESULTS
    804081, 2
    804080, 31
    804079, 38
    804078, 68
    804077, 15
    804076, 54
    804075, 68
    804074, 29
    804073, 4
    804072, 46
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's from medium a tutorial done in python and step-by-step with code explanation
[19-line Line-by-line Python Perceptron](https://medium.com/@thomascountz/19-line-line-by-line-python-perceptron-b6f113b161f3)

Comment: I'd suggest before you jump right into code, try to understand what perceptron really is, and the math behind it (don't get too involved in the math if you are interested in the program only).